# ¿Como lanzar una actividad 5 veces con un botón y después volver a la mainActivity?

Tags: java, android, activity

Me gustaría lanzar una actividad varias veces con un botón y cuando se haya llamado 5 veces ejecutar otra. Lo he intentado de la siguiente forma pero no consigo que funcione.

```
public class SumasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sumas);
            final String stage_temp = getIntent().getStringExtra("stage");
            final int stage = Integer.parseInt(""+stage_temp)+1;
            Toast.makeText(SumasActivity.this, "Stage: "+stage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Muestra 2 (envio 1 desde una actividad que lanza a esta) pero se cierra cuando más abajo intento volver a iniciar esta misma actividad enviando de nuevo la variable stage incrementada.
            ...
             bt1.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick( View view) {
                    if(stage==5) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(SumasActivity.this, Inicio.class);
                        i.putExtra("dificultad", dificultad);
                        i.putExtra("stage", stage);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }else{
                        Intent i = new Intent(SumasActivity.this, SumasActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("dificultad", dificultad);
                        i.putExtra("stage", stage);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                 }
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cual es el error o que es lo que no funciona, no se abre?

Comment: Me manda al MainActivity sin motivo. Yo creo que peta la actividad pero no da error.

Comment: MainActivity es SumasActivity? Nunca te lleva a SumasActivity es el problema?

Comment: 5 ó menos click te lleva a Inicio y mas de 5 te lleva a la que ya estas(SumasActivity)?

Comment: Perdón, siempre me lleva a Inicio y quiero que me lleve a SumasActivity 5 veces (cada vez aparece una operación matematica), después de la 5º operación quiero que me lleve a Inicio. Pero como digo la actividad se cierra y me lleva a la primera a Inicio. También he de decir que si comento la variable stage la actividad no se cierra y se ejecuta bien.

Comment: He añadido un Toast en el código para dar algo más de luz al problema.

Comment: en tu código estas llamando 5 veces a inicio.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me auto contesto, el problema era porque estaba mezclando string y int.

He cambiado esto:

```
final String stage_temp = getIntent().getStringExtra("stage");
final int stage = Integer.parseInt(""+stage_temp)+1;
```

por esto:

```
final int stage = getIntent().getIntExtra("stage",0)+1;
```

y ya me funciona.

Comment: Muy bien. Y también cambiaste stage<=5 por stage==5